# django 2.1 Cannot delete Item

Tags: django

i want to delete element from table Video, and return me this error,

```
Deleting the Video 'add test video' would require deleting the following protected related objects:

Video Title: dadsadas
```

this is my curent models:

```
class Videos(models.Model):

    Title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False, help_text='video title')



class TitleVideo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False,
                             help_text='youtube video title')

    video = models.ForeignKey(Videos, related_name='video_id',
                              null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

i want do this : when i delete item from table Videos, automatic remove all titles related to videos items, how i can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the `ForeignKey` Relation On Delete `CASCADE`:

```
video = models.ForeignKey(Videos, related_name='video_id',
                          null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Please see the documentation [on_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) regarding what should be done on `ForeignKey` Child objects(Here `TitleVideo`) if parent Object(Here the `Video`) is deleted.